# C++ rvalue reference behaviour (specific example)

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I'm currently trying to get libc++ to compile and run with MSVC.  In doing so I encountered a nasty bug (at least what I think is a bug) which has taken me a while to pin down.  I have the following repro code:

```
int globalInt = 666;

class mini_move_iterator
{
public:

    mini_move_iterator(int* i) : __i(i){}

    int&& operator*() const
    {
        return static_cast<int&&>(*__i);
    }

    int* __i;
};

void foo(int&& rval)
{
    // Smash stack
    char stackUser[1000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
        stackUser[i] = 0xff;

    rval += 1;
}

int main()
{
    mini_move_iterator mmi(&globalInt);
    foo(*mmi);
    return 0;
}
```

I have a few questions:

1) Is this legal, i.e. have I avoided straying into the realms of undefined behaviour (it is certainly syntactically legal)?

2) What is the expected value of the global variable *globalInt* after foo returns (undefined may be an acceptable answer)?

**EDIT:**

I should have made clear that this isn't working in VS with MSVC 12.  In *foo* the variable *rval* is pointing to a temporary on the stack and thus the global variable is never incremented.

The temporary is created in int&& operator*() const.  If I replace:

```
return static_cast<int&&>(*__i);
```

with

```
return std::move(*i);
```

then all is well.  Using a C-cast also causes the temporary to be created.

Comment: Let me guess, MSVC is creating a temporary with that `static_cast`? It shouldn't.

Comment: Spot on!  Known issue?

Comment: I was just guessing from the way you framed your question. But I won't be surprised if it's a known bug.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes it was rather leading.  I added a little extra detail to the post.  I'll see if I can find a bug report and if not, report one.

Comment: Why do you think there's a bug? What happens? You never said. (Guesses in the comments don't count)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 1) Is this legal, i.e. have I avoided straying into the realms of
>   undefined behaviour (it is certainly syntactically legal)?

You are so, so close. `__i` is a reserved identifier, and the conversion of `0xff` to `char` is likely implementation-defined. Other than that, this code is valid and the behavior is well-defined.

> 2) What is the expected value of the global variable `globalInt` after
>   foo returns (undefined may be an acceptable answer)?

`667`. The reference returned by `static_cast<int&&>(*__i)` binds directly to `*__i` - i.e., `globalInt`. No temporary should be created. The applicable rule, in [expr.static.cast]/p3, has remained substantially the same since C++11, so you are definitely seeing a compiler bug here.

It looks like this bug has been fixed in the next version of VC++, based on testing on http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/ .

Comment: Ha, nice on the __i comment.  That code was cribbed from libcxx, where its use is valid.  Thanks for the link to the cloud compiler.  Never seen that before.  And yes indeed, it seems to work in there.  No help for me as I need it to work in earlier versions.

Comment: Can you tell me why globalInt should be 667 and not in undefined state?

Comment: Interesting qn Logman.  I presume what you're asking is what the guarantees are on a C++ lvalue after you convert it to an rvalue reference?  From an implementation I "know" it'll be in a definited state (modulo compiler bugs!) but from a standards point of view I'm not sure what you can infer.  Does it become an xvalue and thus in an undefined state?  I'd have to leave that to someone better versed on the standards than me unfortunately!

Answer (score 1):

In *The C++ programming language (4th edition)*, Stroustrup states (§7.7.2, pg. 195):

> [...] the standard library provides a `move()` function: `move(x)` means `static_cast<X&&>(x)` where `X` is the type of `x`.

More precisely, from the C++11 standard (iso.20.2.3):

> `template <class T> typename remove_reference<T>::type&& move(T&& t) noexcept;`
>   *Returns*: `static_cast<typename remove_reference<T>::type&&>(t)`.

If your type `T` is an int, `std::move()` and `static_cast<int&&>()` are exactly the same thing.

So, if MSVC gives different results when switching from one to another, it's clearly a bug.

Comment: The definition of `std::move` is a bit more complicated than that; BS is paraphrasing.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I've updated my answer pasting from the standard.